# "markov_model_cpp" not resolved from current namespace (ChannelAttribution)

Tags: r

I need to use markovchain method in R 
i referred from this doc https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ChannelAttribution/ChannelAttribution.pdf

```
data(PathData)
library(markovchain)
library(ChannelAttribution)
markov_model(Data, "path", "total_conversions",
 var_value="total_conversion_value", var_null="total_null", out_more=TRUE)
```

when i run it throws the error

```
Error in .Call("markov_model_cpp", Data, var_path, var_conv, var_value,  : 
  "markov_model_cpp" not resolved from current namespace (ChannelAttribution)
```

can anyone find me a solution

Answer (score 0):

ChannelAtttribution 1.11 has some issues. You could download ChannelAttribution 1.10 or wait ChannelAttribution 1.12 that will be on CRAN in 1/2 days.

Davide